# Infinitely small quantities defined by Cauchy

Tags: calculus, math-history, infinitesimals

I am reading Cauchy's book about analysis [0] and there he defines an infinitesimal quantity of first order as

$k\alpha$ **or at least** $k\alpha(1±\epsilon)$,

an infinitesimal quantity of second order as

$k\alpha^2$ **or at least** $k\alpha^2(1±\epsilon)$,

...

where $k$ denotes a finite quantity different from zero and $\epsilon$ denotes a variable number that decreases indefinitely with the numerical value of $\alpha$. What is this "or at least $k\alpha^n(1±\epsilon)$"? And what is the motivation behind it?

[0] Cauchy’s Cours d’analyse: An Annotated Translation - Bradley and Sandifer

Thanks

Comment: He probably wanted it to keep getting smaller so he could pull off a limit-type thing.

Comment: Why did you chose to read such an old book ? And have you already studied the modern formulation or is this you first calculus experience ?

Comment: I think that he is trying to avoid [Bishop Berkeley's ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst#Content)... Cauchy is "founding" calculus on *number* (instead of geometry: compare with [L’Hôpital's Analyse](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319171142)): thus (see page 22)  an infinitely small quantity is "a variable whose **numerical value**
decreases indefinitely"; basically (see page 21) a sequence $x_n$. But what about "the limit" ? If $\alpha$ decrease "down to $0$" we have that the ratio $k \dfrac {\alpha}{\alpha}$ has to face with the infamous $\dfrac 0 0$...

Comment: I looking for the foundations of analysis. From wikipedia: ..._italic_a French mathematician reputed as a pioneer of analysis. He was one of the first to state and prove theorems of calculus rigorously, rejecting the heuristic principle of the generality of algebra of earlier authors._italic_. I have already studied the modern calculus but with a terrible book, so now I am trying to re-study everything again :)

Comment: I think 0/0 is not a problem for ideas because (page 22): _Here, Cauchy is making the implicit assumption that \alpha is never zero._

Comment: Probably it reflects a step in the "evolution" of Cauchy's thinking, that can be investigated (if any) only on manuscript sources. Compare with the 1823 version : [Résumé des leçons sur le calcul infinitésimal](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA7) : [page 4] the def of *infinitesimal* is the same; [page 7] now the *infinitesimal* is simply denoted with : $i= \alpha h$ where $h$ is a finite quantity.

Answer (score 2):

For pity's sake OP, don't try to learn analysis from the *Cours d'Analyse*.  There's at least one serious and subtle error -- [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250968/where-is-cauchys-wrong-proof/)), and it is not by modern standards rigorous.  That said, it's a fascinating book, especially if you are interested in Cauchy's ideas about infinitesimals.

In the première partie chapitre II, Cauchy introduces an 'infinitely small quantity' $\alpha$ which he says means 'a variable whose numerical values decrease indefinitely.' When such an $\alpha$ is fixed we can talk about infinitely small quantities of first order, second order, and so on, which are related to powers of $\alpha$.

Cauchy first says that a variable quantity is called *infinitely small of the first order* if its ratio with $\alpha$ converges to a finite nonzero limit (as $\alpha$ decreases to zero).  You should regard that as Cauchy's definition.  One *example* of an infinitely small quantity of first order  is $k\alpha$ where $k$ is finite and nonzero.

More generally we can restate the definition by writing down the most general quantity which satisfies it. A quantity whose ratio with $\alpha$ tends to $k$ takes the form
$$ \alpha k (1+\epsilon)$$
where $\epsilon$ is some quantity that tends to zero as $\alpha$ does. So a quantity is *infinitely small of the first order* iff it has that form for some finite nonzero $k$.  The reason for the $\pm$ is probably that Cauchy tends to deal with infinitesimal quantities which are always positive (all the examples at the start of that chapter are).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. After reading this book I'll try to read something like Rudin (very rigorous proofing).
Sorry, but I did not understand why is ak(1 + e) **the most general quantity**? How can you be sure about that? Just as an example, the expression ak(1 + e + e^2) does not fit also?

Comment: $\alpha k (1+\epsilon+\epsilon^2)$ still has the same form because it is $\alpha k $ times 1+ something tending to zero.  It is the "most general" because if $ \beta/\alpha \to k$ then $\beta = \alpha k (1 + k^{-1}(\beta/\alpha - k ))$ and $k^{-1}(\beta/\alpha-k)$ tends to 0 since $k$ is finite so this is of the form $\alpha k (1+ \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ tends to 0 with $\alpha$.

Comment: Humm I see, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy is interested in generalizing $k\alpha^2$ to $k\alpha^2(1±\epsilon)$ because he has in mind polynomial expressions in the infinitesimal $\alpha$.  Any such polynomial would take the form $k\alpha^n(1±\epsilon)$ rather than merely $\alpha^n$ (where $\epsilon$ is another infinitesimal). Cauchy has a whole series of results on such infinitesimals in his *Cours d'Analyse*, as analyzed in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-011-9235-x).